# My string compare is coming out wrong

Tags: c, string, strcmp

hi my program is to enter a number which gives the length of the string then the string and then finally a letter which should then tell me how many times that letter is in the string. Currently to help me figure out what is wrong with my code i can see that the strcmp is resulting in the same ascii number but negative. eg for the letter a the number is 97 but the strcmp is giving out -97 so the strcmo doesnt show the character as being in the string and results in the incorrect result. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks
    #include 
    #include

```
int main(void)
{
  char myChar[100], z, k;
  int counter, n, g=0, r, i, l;
  counter=0;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  while (counter<n)
  {
    counter++;
    scanf(" %c",&myChar[counter]);
  }

  scanf(" %s", &z);

  for(i=0;i<n+1;++i)
  {
    k=myChar[i];
    r=strcmp(&z, &k); 
    l=r;    
    //printf("\n%c", myChar[i]);
    printf("%d\n", l);
    if(r==0)
    {
        g++;
        printf("%d\n", g);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\n%d\n", g);


  return (0);
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` needs null-terminated strings. `&z` and `&k` are not unless `z` and `k` are both null characters. Even before that, `%s` needs space for the string it stores. Unless the input is nothing, it's going to go out of bounds on `&k`.

Comment: You are comparing individual characters, not strings.

Comment: You need to go back and refresh yourself on the difference between a single character (`char`) and a string (which is represented variously as `char*` or `char[n]`).  It's very confusing in C.

Comment: @HotLicks: A `char*` may *point* to a string; it is not itself a string. A "string" is by definition "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character", not a pointer.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I said "represented"; I didn't say "is".  That, in fact, is the biggest part of the problem -- a "string" in C doesn't really exist.  It's only the imagination of the programmer that makes something a "string".

Comment: @HotLicks: A `char*` doesn't *represent* a string; it *refers to* a string (think about the way the word "representation" is used in the C standard). And a string certainly does exist, defined as I quoted above. There's no string *type* in C, but an array of `char` may *contain* a string. It's a data layout, not a data type.

Comment: I wasn't using "represented" as a C lawyer.  But my point is that you can't point at anything and say "that's a string", without knowing how it's used (if even then).

Comment: and `counter++; scanf(" %c",&myChar[counter]);` : `myChar[0]` is not used. Double loop is required.

Comment: A `char*` can represent a string conceptually. Unfortunately, programming in C and thinking conceptually are somewhat at odds.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char myChar[100], str[64];//
    int counter, n;
    int i, j, k;

    printf("number of charactors : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i=0; i<n; ++i){
        scanf(" %c", &myChar[i]);
    }

    printf("input string : ");
    scanf("%63s", str);//"%s" : The useless one letter to input as a string. "%c" for &z

    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        counter = 0;
        for(j=0;str[j]!='\0'; ++j){
            k = (str[j] == myChar[i]);//Comparison of each character
            counter += k;//if(str[j] == myChar[i]) ++counter;
        }
        printf("%c is %d\n", myChar[i], counter);
    }

    return (0);
}
```